# Swift: how to change annotation image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to make an app that uses mapkit to display custom pins. One of the requirements is to cluster the pins and show the number of clustered pins.

The problem is that I am trying to do this is swift and there are no solutions for it. I tried different libraries and the only one that I managed to make it to work is this one:

https://github.com/RVLVR/REVClusterMap

I am able to add annotations and they cluster when I zoom out, but I am unable to change their picture. This is what I got so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: REVClusterMapView!

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 43.719880, longitude: -79.467060)
        centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)

        var myAnn: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        let coordonate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.717880, longitude: -79.462060)

        var ann = CustomPointAnnotation()
        ann.coordinate = coordonate
        ann.title = "MyPin"
        ann.subtitle = "some text"
        ann.imageName = "restaurant_pin"

        myAnn.addObject(ann)

        myMap.addAnnotations(myAnn as [AnyObject])
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
            regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        myMap.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

    func myMap(myMap: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        println("delegate called")

        if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "test"

        var anView = myMap.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            anView.annotation = annotation
        }

        //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
        //the view is dequeued or created...

        let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
        println(cpa.imageName)
        anView.image = UIImage(named: cpa.imageName)

        return anView
    }

    class CustomPointAnnotation: REVClusterPin {
        var imageName: String!
    }

}
```

In the console there is no "delegate called" message. How do I make it call it and is this delegate ok?

In Objective-C it looks like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation class] == MKUserLocation.class) {
        //userLocation = annotation;
        return nil;
    }

    REVClusterPin *pin = (REVClusterPin *)annotation;

    MKAnnotationView *annView;

    if( [pin nodeCount] > 0 ){
        pin.title = @"___";

        annView = (REVClusterAnnotationView*)
        [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"cluster"];

        if( !annView )
            annView = (REVClusterAnnotationView*)
            [[[REVClusterAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                  reuseIdentifier:@"cluster"] autorelease];

        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cluster.png"];

        [(REVClusterAnnotationView*)annView setClusterText:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[pin nodeCount]]];

        annView.canShowCallout = NO;
    } else {
        annView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];

        if( !annView )
            annView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                    reuseIdentifier:@"pin"] autorelease];

        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinpoint.png"];
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;   

        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-6.0, 0.0);
    }
    return annView;
}
```

I am sorry for the stupid question, but I have struggled for days to find a working library and now I can't understand this. Moreover, I am new to IOS, and Objective-C is a pretty hard language for beginners.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can change the image of an existing annotation; I think you have to remove the annotation and replace it with one that has a different image.

Comment: I think that the "delegate called" message is not showing because you are not setting your viewController as the delegate of your `REVClusterMapView` instance. Add `myMap.delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I think the image of an existing annotation can be changed as long as the image state logic is also in the viewForAnnotation delegate method.  Anyway, the viewForAnnotation delegate method in the Swift code is named wrong.  You can't use `func myMap(...)` -- it has to be `func mapView(...)`.  Of course, also make sure delegate property is set like gabuh commented.  I am assuming REVClusterMapView is a subclass of MKMapView or that it has the same delegate method signatures as MKMapView.

Comment: @AndreiDobrin  How can I remove old pings when a result is not found.?

Comment: @ilesh , sorry, I do not do Swift programming anymore (for the last 2 years) and I do not have the code anymore... Maybe you can post a question and somebody will know